# Function changing image won't work, why

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to create function that sets the url to photo and then changing background image of selected div with that photo.

```
function changePhoto(id) {
            var y = document.getElementById("baza_big_photo");
            y.style.display = "block";
            var z = '"' + "url(" + "'" + "./assets/min_images/" + id + ".jpg" + "'" + ")" + '"';
                y.style.backgroundImage = z;
                console.log(z);
        }
```

For example, I send tn_baza01 (name of photo) as a parameter, but the image is not showing in my bigger div :(

I have 20 small divs with different id's and one big on top of it. When I click on small image it should change bigger div background-image to that image.

Comment: Why all the concatination on the url? Why not just do `z = 'url("/assets/min_images/'+id+'.jpg")'; Might not be the problem, but simplifies the code a bit at least. What does the console.log return?

Comment: remove the surrounding quotes `"`

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie it's indead the problem. +1 for good guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be wrapping the `url(..)` in `"`

So changing it to

```
var z = "url('./assets/min_images/" + id + ".jpg')";
```

should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation in `var z` is creating a string like `"url('./assets/min_images/tn_baza01.jpg')"` and the leading/trailing quotes are invalid.

Update that line to this to remove the leading/trailing quotes

```
var z = "url(" + "'" + "./assets/min_images/" + id + ".jpg" + "'" + ")";
```

and it will create a string like `url('./assets/min_images/tn_baza01.jpg')`

As long as the image path is valid, that should work fine.

```js
function changePhoto(id) {
            var y = document.getElementById("baza_big_photo");
            y.style.display = "block";
            var z = "url(" + "'" + "./assets/min_images/" + id + ".jpg" + "'" + ")";
            y.style.backgroundImage = z;
        }

changePhoto('tn_baza01');
```

```html
<div id="baza_big_photo"></div>
```